# How do you check if a method has returned true

Tags: c#, oop

```
Public bool SqlCheck(string username, string password) 
{
    // sql checks here 
    return true
}
```

How do I check whether this has returned true or false in my main method? A code example would be helpful.

Does the boolean have a default value I should be aware of?

Comment: Another thing that would also be nice here as well (IMO) is to make your method name more descriptive.  You may not be the only one reading your code in the future, and `if (SqlCheck(username, password))` doesn't really provide anything useful to someone reading your code.  Perhaps something like, `AreSqlCredentialsValid` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You simply have something like:

```
bool result = SqlCheck(username, password);

if (result)
{
    // Worked!
}
else
{
    // Failed
}
```

If you don't need the result after the test you can simply have:

```
if (SqlCheck(username, password))
{
    // Worked!
}
else
{
    // Failed
}
```

`bool` defaults to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this:

```
if (SqlCheck(username, password))
{
    // SqlCheck returned true
}
else
{
    // SqlCheck returned false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

The `IF` clause need a boolean (true or false) so your can do

> **MSDN** The if statement selects a statement for execution based on the value of a Boolean expression.

#### Sample

```
 if (SqlCheck("UserName", "Password"))
 {
     // SqlCheck returns true
 }
 else 
 {
     // SqlCheck returns false
 } 


public bool SqlCheck(string username, string password) 
{
 // sql checks here 
    return true;
}
```

**If you need the result later you can save it to a variable.**

```
 bool sqlCheckResult= SqlCheck("UserName", "Password");
 if (sqlCheckResult)
 {
     // SqlCheck returns true
 }
 else 
 {
     // SqlCheck returns false
 } 

 // do something with your sqlCheckResult variable
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - if-else (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a C# programmer, but I'd imagine when you call this method in your `main` method it will return the return value of `SqlCheck` will it not?

Pseudo-code:

```
public void function main()
{
    bool result = SqlCheck('martin', 'changeme');

    if (result == true) {
        // result was true
    } else {
        // result was false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is a system type with two values understood by `if`s, `while`s, `for`s etc. of the .NET. You check for true value like this:

```
if (SqlCheck(string username, string password) ) {
    // This will be executed only if the method returned true
}
```

The default value of `bool` variables is `false`. This applies only to class/struct variables: local ones need to be initialized explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

in your main method you can do this:

```
bool sqlCheck = SqlCheck("username", "password");

if(sqlCheck) // ie it is true
{
    // do something
}
```

but your method is only returning true at the moment, I'm sure you will be doing other things in here to verify if the sql check is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool myCheck = SqlCheck(myUser, myPassword);
```

OR

```
bool myCheck = SqlCheck("user", "root");
```

Here user and root are actual strings to check....

```
if (myCheck) {
    // succeeded
} else {
    //failed
}
```